# Olympic Athletics Track

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, gif-format

Writing:

```
L = 42.195;
R = 36.500 + Union[{0.30}, Table[1.22 n + 0.20, {n, 8}]];

ρ[r_, ω_, t_, ϕ_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[(r/Sin[ω t + ϕ])^2], ArcTan[r/L] <= Mod[ω t + ϕ, π] <= π - ArcTan[r/L]},
                                {Sqrt[(L Cos[ω t + ϕ])^2] + Sqrt[r^2 - (L Sin[ω t + ϕ])^2], True}}]
γ[r_, ω_, t_, ϕ_] := ρ[r, ω, t, ϕ] {Cos[ω t + ϕ], Sin[ω t + ϕ]}

rings = Table[ParametricPlot[γ[R[[n]], 1, t, 0], {t, 0, 2π}, PlotStyle -> Pink], {n, 9}];

line = Graphics[{Green, Line[{{L, -R[[1]]}, {L, -R[[9]]}}]}];

Φ = Table[f[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Norm[D[γ[R[[n]], 1, t, x - ArcTan[R[[n]]/L]], t]], {t, 0, 2π - x}];   
          FindRoot[f[x] == 4 L + 2π R[[1]], {x, 0}][[1, 2]] - ArcTan[R[[n]]/L], {n, 9}];

points = Table[Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[Large], Point[γ[R[[n]], 1, t, Φ[[n]]]]}], {n, 9}, {t, 0, 2π, 2π/25}];

frames = Table[Show[{rings, line, Transpose[points][[n]]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"x [m]", "y [m]"}, 
               PlotRange -> {{-90, 90}, {-60, 60}}, ImageSize -> 1000], {n, 26}];

Export["image.gif", frames, "AnimationRepetitions" -> ∞, "DisplayDurations" -> 0.5];
```

I get:

[image]

in which there are two things that don't convince me:

1. the slowness of the code, if you could speed it up a bit it would be a good thing;
2. the fact that they don't reach the green finish line all together, even if the start is staggered and the angular velocity is set unitary.

Ideas what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

---

Thanks to the answers of *Michael E2* and *cvgmt* I realized that I was unnecessarily complicating the problem (in addition to being stubborn about the angular velocity) and I changed the code to the following:

```
L = 42.195;
R = 36.500 + Union[{0.30}, Table[1.22 n + 0.20, {n, 8}]];

v0 = 9.3;
T = (4 L + 2 π R)/v0;
s[s0_, t_] := s0 + v0 t

γ[r_, s0_, t_] := Piecewise[{
    {{L + r Sin[s[s0, t]/r], -r Cos[s[s0, t]/r]}, 0 <= s[s0, t] <= π r},
    {{L + π r - s[s0, t], r}, π r <= s[s0, t] <= 2 L + π r},
    {{-L + r Sin[(s[s0, t] - 2 L)/r], -r Cos[(s[s0, t] - 2 L)/r]}, 2 L + π r <= s[s0, t] <= 2 L + 2 π r},
    {{-3 L - 2 π r + s[s0, t], -r}, 2 L + 2 π r <= s[s0, t] <= 4 L + 2 π r}}]

space = Table[f[s0_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Norm[D[γ[R[[n]], s0, t], t]], {t, 0, T[[n]]}];
              Chop[Quiet[FindRoot[f[s0] == 4 L + 2 \[Pi] R[[1]], {s0, 0}]][[1, 2]]], {n, 9}];

rings = Table[ParametricPlot[γ[R[[n]], 0, t], {t, 0, T[[n]]}, PlotStyle -> Pink], {n, 9}];

lines = Graphics[{Green, Line[{{L, R[[1]]}, {L, R[[9]]}}], Line[{{-L, R[[1]]}, {-L, R[[9]]}}], 
                   Line[{{-L, -R[[1]]}, {-L, -R[[9]]}}], Line[{{L, -R[[1]]}, {L, -R[[9]]}}]}];

points = Table[Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[Medium], Point[γ[R[[n]], space[[n]], t]]}],
               {t, 0, T[[1]], T[[1]]/22}, {n, 9}];

frames = Table[Show[{rings, lines, points[[n]]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
                Epilog -> {Text[Style[StringJoin["t = ", ToString[NumberForm[T[[1]] (n - 1)/22,
                           {∞, 2}]], " s"], Red, Bold, 20], {15, 5}],
                           Text[Style[StringJoin["s = ", ToString[NumberForm[space[[1]] + v0 T[[1]] (n - 1)/22,
                           {∞, 2}]], " m"], Red, Bold, 20], {15, 10}]}, PlotRange -> {{-90, 90}, {-50, 50}},
                Ticks -> {Range[-90, 90, 10], Range[-50, 50, 10]}, ImageSize -> 1000], {n, 23}];

Export["image.gif", frames, "AnimationRepetitions" -> ∞, "DisplayDurations" -> 1];
```

getting what I wanted:

[image]

On the other hand, *flinty*'s answer opened up new avenues for me, as well as confirming the fact that when you think about something MMA has already thought about it for years!

Comment: I don't think that fixed angular velocity will make them come to the finish line together -- you can see that the outer runner is much faster than the inner one. You should set their "proper" (linear) velocities to be equal.

Comment: The position at distance `s` (arclength) from finishing line on a lane of straightaway length `L` and turn radius `R`: `ClearAll[pos];
pos[s_, L_, R_] := pos[s, L, R, 2 (L + Pi R)];
pos[s_, L_, R_, T_] := With[{s0 = Mod[s, T]},
   Piecewise[{
     {{L/2, 0} + R {Sin[s0/R], -Cos[s0/R]}, s0 < Pi R},
     {{L/2, R} + {-s0 + Pi R, 0}, s0 < Pi R + L},
     {{-L/2, 0} + R {Sin[(s0 - L)/R], -Cos[(s0 - L)/R]}, 
      s0 < 2 Pi R + L},
     {{-L/2, -R} + {s0 - L - 2 Pi R, 0}, s0 < T}
     }]
   ];`. Starting positions at `s = -400` meters, I suppose, for appropriate `L` and `R`s.

Comment: Example: `myP = Table[pos[s, 2, R], {R, 1, 1.5, 0.1}];
ParametricPlot[myP, {s, -2 (2 + Pi), 0}, Mesh -> 9]`. I leave the rest to you, if you find this helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's my attempt without using formulae but using a `StadiumShape` discretization instead, mainly to show another way to do it for better performance:

```
width = 42.195;
radii = 36.500 + Union[{0.30}, Table[1.22 n + 0.20, {n, 8}]];
(* generate some tracks as StadiumShape discretizations *)
tracks = Table[
   DiscretizeRegion[
    RegionBoundary[StadiumShape[{{-width/2, 0}, {width/2, 0}}, r]],
    MaxCellMeasure -> .1], {r, radii}];

(* Create lines from StadiumShape track coordinates *)
track2line[tr_] := Line@MeshCoordinates@tr

(* Interpolations of the coordinates to get parametric curves *)
intps = With[{c = MeshCoordinates@#},
  {Length@c, Interpolation /@ Transpose[c]}
 ] & /@ tracks;

(* get the position at t for the nth curve *)
curves[n_, t_] := Quiet[#[t*intps[[n, 1]]] & /@ intps[[n, 2]]]

(* relative lengths of the tracks compared to innermost *)
rellengths = #/#[[1]] &@(RegionMeasure /@ tracks);

start = .4;
anim = Animate[
  Graphics[{Red, track2line /@ tracks, Blue, 
    Point[Table[
      curves[i, Mod[(t - start)/#, 1] &@rellengths[[i]]], {i, 
       Length@tracks}]]}]
  , {t, -start, start}]
```

[image: olympic track StadiumShape animation]

Not sure if it's entirely correct logic, but they all arrive at the finish line  at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Use `{s,-400,0}` we can get the result by the author.

```
l = 42.195;
radiis = 36.500 + Union[{0.30}, Table[1.22 n + 0.20, {n, 8}]];
c1[r_][s_] = {l, 0} + r*{Cos[-π/2 + s/r], Sin[-π/2 + s/r]};
c2[r_][s_] = {-l, 0} + r*{Cos[π/2 + s/r], Sin[π/2 + s/r]};
l1[r_][s_] = {l, r} + s*{-1, 0};
l2[r_][s_] = {-l, -r} + s*{1, 0};
arc[r_] = π*r + 2 l + π*r + 2 l;
c[r_][s_] = 
  Which[0 <= s <= π*r, c1[r][s], 0 <= s - π*r <= 2 l, 
   l1[r][s - π*r], 0 <= s - π*r - 2 l <= π*r, 
   c2[r][s - π*r - 2 l], 0 <= s - π*r - 2 l - π*r <= 2 l, 
   l2[r][s - π*r - 2 l - π*r]];
cc[r_][s_] = c[r][Mod[s, arc[r]]];
fig = Show[
   Table[ParametricPlot[c[r][s], {s, 0, arc[r]}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Thin, Red}], {r, radiis}], PlotRange -> All];
Manipulate[
 Show[fig, 
  Graphics[{{Green, 
     Line[{cc[First@radiis][0], cc[Last@radiis][0]}]}, {Point@
      Table[cc[r][s], {r, radiis}]}}]], {s, -400, 0}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

[image]